# C# How to DateTimeOffset.Parse 2022003023T05:57:44.200Z?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetimeoffset

I tried `DateTimeOffset dto = DateTime.ParseExact("2022003023T05:57:44.200Z", "yyyyMMMMdd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);` but to no avail: `'String '2022003023T05:57:44.200Z' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'`

Comment: There is no such datetime value.

Comment: What date should this be: 2022003023 ?

Comment: also MMMM is **full name** of the month[...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kEGnux)

Answer (score 0):

(Would be a mess as a comment)
If those extra 0's were typos for separators (2022/03/23T05:57:44.200Z being the real value), then:

```
void Main()
{
    string s = "2022003023T05:57:44.200Z";
    var ss = s.ToCharArray();
    ss[4] = '/';
    ss[7] = '/';
    var dt = new string(ss); 
    DateTimeOffset dto = DateTime.Parse(dt);
    Console.WriteLine(dto);
}
```